# Button click not working after document is printed javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a div that contains text to be printed on external printers.

```
<div id="school">
<p>Who loves school?</p>
 <img onClick=clickMe(1) src='clickImage.png' />
</div>
```

Below is the javascript that handles the click of the above image button and initiates a printing dialog,

```
  function clickMe(id) {
    const printContents = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
            const originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;
            document.body.innerHTML = printContents;
            window.print();
            document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
  }
```

The above javascript prints the div successfully, but with only 1 problem. After the print dialog exits, the image button stops responding to clicks until the page is refreshed.

Ideal behavior would be the button responding on each click without the need to refresh the page.

What am I missing?

Comment: That's a very bad idea. You have to use CSS directives for this. `<link media="print" href="print.css" />` wher you put `display : none` for unprinting parts  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link#attr-media

Comment: @MisterJojo is right. also, you are removng the img on which you have the event, so you would need to bind a new event on it again.

Comment: It seems work for me by just the part of code you post???